# Creating multiple carts for every session

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I m trying to build an e-commerce website using rails.
I have  controller( line_items_controller.rb)
I have created a concern/set_cart module
**This is my line_items_controller.rb**

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart,only: [:create]
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /line_items
  # GET /line_items.json
  def index
    @line_items = LineItem.all
  end

  # GET /line_items/1
  # GET /line_items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /line_items/new
  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new
  end

  # GET /line_items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /line_items
  # POST /line_items.json
  def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    # @line_item = LineItem.new(line_item_params)
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product)
    @cart.user_id = current_user.id
    @cart.save
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /line_items/1
  # DELETE /line_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @line_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to line_items_url, notice: 'Line item was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_line_item
      @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
      li = LineItem.find(params[:id])
      puts "This item is for #{li.product.title}"
      
      
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def line_item_params
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id, :cart_id) #Check this
    end
end
```

**This is my module concerns/current_cart.rb**

```
module CurrentCart
  private

   def set_cart
     @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
     rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
     @cart = Cart.create

     session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  end

  
end
```

Each time I log in and a new cart is being created. I have a column user_id in carts table.

**As soon as I log in if the user id is present I don't want to create a new cart. Just want the existing cart**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please do not abuse the version tags. They are used just to provide context about which version of Rails the question applies to and hanging them all on there like ornaments won't garner any additional attention to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might not have your `rescue` block set properly. Here's [some more info](https://stackify.com/rescue-exceptions-ruby/) on error handling. Try this:

```
def set_cart
  begin
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  end
end
```

Alternatively, without a rescue block:

```
def set_cart
  if session[:cart_id]
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  else
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  end
end
```